# How is README.in used in autotools?

Tags: autotools

I'm using acmkdir to initialize a new project and it created a README.in file and a README file.

Is README.in actually used by something to create the README? If not, what is its purpose? I'm hoping to understand all of the files created by acmkdir and these have me stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **README.in** file is the "souce file" for your README. On make your README.in will be processed for variables like **@VERSION@** and the proper values for your build will be inserted.

You can see an example [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#4sK25pC4wlY/bibletime-1.5.3/README.in&q=README.in).

Comment: nit: make is irrelevant.  README is created at configure time.

Comment: I use it in libraries to automatically update the doxygen documentation, just by writing the `Doxyfile.in` and doing the same explained by Brian ;-)